# Pandas slice rows in multindex dataframe fails

Tags: python, pandas, filter, slice, multi-index

I have the following dataframe, where date ,hour and code are multindex:

```
                                    1         2         3         4       
date           hour      code    
2020-11-01     13         A1        2.3     2.6      7.4         5.3
2020-11-01     13         A2        7.5     7.8      7.6         7.7
2020-11-01     13         A3        4.2     5.3      5.9         6.1
2020-11-02     11         A1        4.3     3.3      9.8         8.5
2020-11-02     11         A2        4.4     8.6      11.1        4.3
2020-11-02     11         A3        4.3     2.1      4.5         3.8
2020-11-02     12         A1        5.4     5.6      5.8         5.7
...
```

I'm trying to slice the dataframe for example to get only the 2020-11-02 hour 11, but I am failing in doing this.I have tried to do it as described [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IndexSlice.html) :

```
df.loc[(slice(None), slice('2020-11-02',11)), :]

>>>
```

but the retuurns empty dataframe (the date is object and the hour is int).
I have also tried :

```
agg.loc[(slice('2020-11-01'), slice(13)), :]
```

but that returns error:

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.date' and
> 'str'

In [this](http://pandas%20how%20to) post I saw that I could do at least select only the date like this :

```
df.loc[['2020-11-02']]
```

but that returns error as well:

> KeyError: "['2020-11-01'] not in index"
> (thought as I mentioned, the date is object)

My end goal is to be able to chart the differnt "codes"  for each date and hoour (for example the 1/11/2020 13:00 will have three lines with columns values 1,2,3,4 , etc)
at the moment i'm stuck in the part of being able to slice multindex dataframe.

**My goal here is to be able to slice the rows I want based on date and hour indices.**

Edit:  The  inndex dtype is object:

```
agg.index.get_level_values(0).dtype
>>>dtype('O')
```

Comment: something like this : ``df.loc[(slice("2020-11-02"), slice(11), slice(None)), :]``

Comment: Looks like `date` is a `datetime` object instead of a `str`

Comment: @BrunoMello is there a way to check the index type when is rows? or to change the type when is index? is like I can't acess this "index column" to change its' type

Comment: Alternatively, you can pass an `axis parameter`: ``df.loc(axis=0)["2020-11-01", 13]``

Comment: Try this, and edit your question https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.dtype.html

Comment: i'm getting dtype('O'). I'm not sure which part I should edit and why

Comment: Your `date` level is `datetime.date`, which should be avoid in Pandas dataframe as they are treated as `Object` dtype. Try to convert `date` into datetime type with `pd.to_datetime`

Comment: @QuangHoang when I print the dtype I get object , will add it now to my question

Comment: @Reut I know it was object, almost everything is object type in Pandas, including strings, lists, sets... please re-read my comment above.

Comment: @QuangHoang thanks you I understood what you means. I have changed the type and it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply have a dtyping problem : you should change the type of your column **date**.

As stated in your error, your column is of dtype **object** containing **datetime.date** objects.

First convert it to a column of dtype **datetime**, they are far easier to work with, even allowing strings to filter dates ! From **datetime.date** objects, it's as simple as :

```py
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Then use direct indexing and it will work directly :

```py
df.loc['2020-11-02', 11]
```

Then, if you want to have more freedom, use pd.IndexSlice :

```py
# All A1
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, :, 'A1']]
# All A1 keeping a triple index :
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, :, 'A1':'A1']]
# All 13 o'clock (keeping a triple index) :
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 13:13, :]]
```